# How can I know if an id belongs to a user or a page through the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an ID and I want to know if it belongs to a Page or a User. How can I know it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access that ID via the API with the `metadata` parameter set to true, the 'type' field in the response will tell you what type of object it is

e.g.

`https://graph.facebook.com/<my user id>?metadata=1`

```
{
   "id": "1234567",
   "name": "xxxxxx",
   "first_name": "xxx",
   "last_name": "xxx",
   "username": "xxx.xxxxx",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "type": "user"
   //removed other metdata
```

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/?metadata=1

{
   "id": "1234567",
   "name": "xxxxxx",
   "first_name": "xxx",
   "last_name": "xxx",
   "username": "xxx.xxxxx",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "type": "user"
   //removed other metdata